# Creating python objects from objects

Tags: python, oop, deep-copy

I need to write a class that takes some raw strings, and then separates them into a list which it holds as attributes. (Among other things, but that's the part I'm concerned with right now.) Something like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, raw, index):
        self.a = raw.split("\n")
        self.index = index
```

So an instance of MyClass will have an attribute .a, that is a list containing lines from the raw string I initialize the object with, as well as an attribute .index that is the index that I give it, correct? However, I would also like to be able to generate additional instances of MyClass that contain only one line of the raw text each, but possessing the same index.

What I am currently thinking of is this:

```
from copy import deepcopy
foo = MyClass("lots of text", 1)
bar = []
for line in foo.a:
    copy = deepcopy(MyClass)
    copy.a = line
    bar.append(copy)
```

Is this the correct way to go about doing this?

Comment: if it's just a list of strings and an index, why don't you use a tuple?

Comment: There's a whole lot more that I'll be doing than I showed here, so I excised most of it for conciseness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strings are stored on the instance `foo`, not the class `MyClass`, so you need to `for line in foo.a`. Other than that, your solution should work.

An alternative solution would be:

```
for line in foo.a:
    bar.append(MyClass(line, foo.index))
```

Or, simply using a list comprehension, which seems to me most pythonic here:

```
bar = [ MyClass(line, foo.index) for line in foo.a ]
```

(One more thing about your original solution, is that it can potentially be inefficient if `foo.a` is huge, because you make a `deepcopy` of it, when all you really need is to copy a single line at a time.)

EDIT: to make this answer complete, consider you want to subclass `MyClass`, and assign an instance of the subclass to `foo`. In this case, using `deepcopy` would preserve the type, while instantiating `MyClass` explicitly would not.  One fix would be to replace `MyClass(...)` with `type(foo)(...)`.

Comment: Oops, yes, that was my mistake with the `foo` versus `MyClass`. Got a bit confused there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From a non OOP perspective, you can simple use a `tuple` and you get the same `bar` values.

```
from copy import deepcopy
foo = ('lots of text', 1)
bar = deepcopy(foo[0].split('\n'))
```

Comment: The OP is requesting for an `OOP` solution.

Comment: Indeed, I'm trying to learn how to use `OOP` properly, and the rest of the code (that I didn't show) does work better from an `OOP `perspective.